# Google Analytics 2 accounts results don't match

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am reporting my traffic to 2 different Google Analytics accounts, using this technique:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-2']);
_gaq.push(['b._setAccount', 'UA-YYYYYYY-2']);
```

It works, however I see that the stats don't really match. In my tests, I see that account "B" gets about 10% less traffic.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Are you sure that you're sending data to both object everywhere? With traffic, do you mean 10% less visits?

Comment: Yes the javascript code is in my headers. And yes I mean about 10% less visits (tested over a couple of days).

Comment: Dig in to data: check the content reports of both accounts for a fixed period of time and see whether the difference distributes evenly and similar over all pages on both accounts. If there's one page which is causing the difference, it's most likely, that this page has some JavaScript flaws in certain (data driven) cases which prevent at least the second account to count properly.

Comment: It looks like it is happening on all pages. Testing over 3 days, the homepage for example had 117 pageviews on the main account and 86 on the "b" account (yes it's a low traffic site).

Comment: I also checked against browser/os, nothing interesting there either... seems random